# Map Flatfile schema with repeating nodes input to one XML schema with repeating nodes output BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I'm trying to map a Flat file schema with multiple lines to an XML file with same multiple lines.

Input file example:

```
Username,"Certification ID","Certification Name","Date completed","Date due"
n2345678,55,"Name","2 Sep 2020",2-Mar-22
n1234567,55,"Name",,19-Mar-21
```

Output file example I would like to build with BizTalk mapper:

```
<Export>
    <Certificate>
        <Username>n2345678</Username> 
        <Date completed>2 Sep 2020</Date completed> 
        <Date due>2-Mar-22</Date due> 
        <Type>HarcodedField</Type> 
        <Kenmerk1>CalculatedField</Kenmerk1> 
        <Certification ID>55</Certification ID> 
        <Certification Name>Name</Certification Name> 
    </Certificate>
    <Certificate>
        <Username>n1234567</Username> 
        <Date completed /> 
        <Date due>19-Mar-21</Date due> 
        <Type>HarcodedField</Type> 
        <Kenmerk1>CalculatedField</Kenmerk1> 
        <Certification ID>55</Certification ID> 
        <Certification Name>Name</Certification Name> 
    </Certificate>
</Export>
```

For now I was only able to generate this output:

```
<Export>
    <Certificate>
        <Username>n2345678</Username> 
        <Date completed>2 Sep 2020</Date completed> 
        <Date due>2-Mar-22</Date due> 
        <Type>HarcodedField</Type> 
        <Kenmerk1>CalculatedField</Kenmerk1> 
        <Certification ID>55</Certification ID> 
        <Certification Name>Name</Certification Name> 
    </Certificate>
</Export>
```

What kind of functoid I had to use to loop on each lines of the input file to generate an output file with one Export node containing several Certificate nodes?

Comment: Are you sure you have both MaxOccurs set correctly on the source and the destination nodes?   You shouldn't have to do any looping then as it will automatically do it.

Comment: Yes I already setted this parameters. I manually generate my input schema maybe it's come from that ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the schemas and show us you rmap.  Without that we are just guessing as to what the problem is.

Comment: I searched and find I had to use the Flat File Schema Wizard to generate properly my xsd regarding the csv provided by my customer. So now the mapping works fine. Thank you @Dijkgraaf

Answer (score 1):

Use the loop shape from the toolbox to map the rows from flat file schema to the "Certificate" from the output schema.
Then set maxOccurs = unbounded on the Certificate element of the output schema and it should work